# Remove first 5 lines from each cell in an MS Word table

Tags: microsoft-word

How can I batch delete the first 5 lines from each cell of the 2nd column of a large table in an MS Word document (preferably Word 2003)?

[image: Before edit]

[image: After edit]

Comment: Your diagram suggests that you mean "in column 1 only". Is that the case?

Answer (score 0):

You can use find and replace:

- select the cells where you want to delete content
- press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to open the dialog box, then press "more" and check "Use wildcards"
- in "find what" enter:
  `[!^13]@^13[!^13]@^13[!^13]@^13[!^13]@^13[!^13]@^13`
  (`([!^13]@^13){5}` should also work but in reality it doesn't)
- leave "replace with" field empty
- press "replace all"

Note: it works correctly only if lines are separated by paragraph mark (<kbd>ENTER</kbd>) and there are less then 10 paragraph marks per cell.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! I tried that and when a cell has more than 5 lines it deletes them all except the last one! To be more specific I want to delete the first 5 lines in each cell and keep the others!